# Pandas add rows according for each unique element of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe, like so:

```
ID A 
0  z
2  z
2  y
5  x
```

To which I want to add rows for each unique value of an ID column:

```
ID A
0  z
2  z
2  y
5  x
0  b
2  b
5  b
```

I'm currently doing so in a very naïve way, which is quite inefficient/slow:

```
IDs = df["ID"].unique()
for ID in IDs: 
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[ID, "b"]], columns=df.columns), ignore_index=True)
```

How would I go to accomplish the same without the explicit foreach, only pandas function calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), rewrite column by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to original `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.append(df.drop_duplicates("ID").assign(A='B'), ignore_index=True)
#alternative
#df = pd.concat([df, df.drop_duplicates("ID").assign(A='B')], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
   ID  A
0   0  z
1   2  z
2   2  y
3   5  x
4   0  B
5   2  B
6   5  B
```